# NGINX - Gunicorn - HTTP 502 upstream prematurely closed

Tags: docker, nginx, gunicorn

I face a very strange behavior into a docker container.
This running was running a while until it crashed, I then mounted the docker container into another infrastructure and since it crashes.

The logs :

```
[INFO] Booting worker with pid: 315
"GET /oidc/authenticate/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0 "https://build.contoso.com/" "<user agent>"
"GET /xxx/yyy/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0 "-" "<user agent>"
"GET /oidc/callback/?state=state&session_state=session_state HTTP/1.1" 302 0 "-" "<user agent>"
[CRITICAL] WORKER TIMEOUT (pid:45)
[error] 306#306: *54 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream, client: 192.168.3.110, server: app, request: "GET /xxx/yyy/ HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:/run/gunicorn.sock:/xxx/yyy/", host: "build.contoso.com"
"GET /xxx/yyy/ HTTP/1.1" 502 559 "-" "<user agent>"
[INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 45)
```

My gunicorn is launched using :

```bash
$VENV/bin/gunicorn app.wsgi:application --daemon --bind unix:/run/gunicorn.sock --workers $workers --capture-output --enable-stdio-inheritance
```

and is up and running :

```bash
p# ps aux | grep gunicorn
root        34  0.0  0.0  30016 20832 ?        S    16:41   0:01 /app/venv/bin/python /app/venv/bin/gunicorn app.wsgi:application --daemon --bind unix:/run/gunicorn.sock --workers 17 --capture-output --enable-stdio-inheritance
root        37  0.0  0.0  66068 52104 ?        S    16:41   0:00 /app/venv/bin/python /app/venv/bin/gunicorn app.wsgi:application --daemon --bind unix:/run/gunicorn.sock --workers 17 --capture-output --enable-stdio-inheritance
[...]
root       413  0.0  0.0   5196   528 pts/0    S+   21:25   0:00 grep gunicorn
```

My nginx configuration:

```
# cat /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/gunicorn
upstream gunicorn {
    server unix:/run/gunicorn.sock;
}

server {
    listen    80;
    server_name    app;

    location /static/ {
        alias /app/static/;
    }

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_pass http://gunicorn;
    }
}
```

Still it crashes, any help welcomed.